# Create Dynamic MinifyJsTask gradle

Tags: gradle, build

I 'm setting up the js minify and I need dynamic configuration files, so I build the following script:

```
def conf = new LinkedHashMap()
conf.resourceSrc = "${projectDir}/src/main/j2ee-apps/store.war/resources/"
conf.distFolder = "${conf.resourceSrc}dist"
//for source propertie see https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin
conf.js = [
    [
        "name": "store",
        "source": fileTree(dir :"${conf.resourceSrc}/store/js", includes :['**/*.js'])  
    ],
    [
        "name": "lib",
        "source": fileTree(dir :"${conf.resourceSrc}/vendor/js/lib", includes :['**/*.js']) 
    ],
    [
        "name": "vendor",
        "source": fileTree(dir :"${conf.resourceSrc}/vendor/js/modules", includes :['**/*.js']) 
    ]
]

task cleanDist(type: Delete) {
    description 'Clean dist folder'
    delete conf.distFolder
}

task generateTask << {
    conf.js.each { js->
        createCombineTask(js, conf).execute()
        createMinifyJsTask(js, conf).execute()      
    }
}

def createCombineTask(js, conf){
    return tasks.create("combine-${js.name}.js", com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.CombineJsTask) {
        source = js.source
        dest = file("${conf.distFolder}/${js.name}.js")
    }
} 

def createMinifyJsTask(js, conf){
    def baseName = "${conf.distFolder}/${js.name}" 

    tasks.create("minify-${js.name}.js", com.eriwen.gradle.js.tasks.MinifyJsTask){
        source = file("${baseName}.js")
        dest = file("${baseName}.min.js")
        sourceMap = file("${baseName}.min.js.map")
        closure {
            warningLevel = 'QUIET'
            compilerOptions.languageIn = 'ECMASCRIPT5'
        }
        doLast {
            def md5 = getFileMD5("${baseName}.min.js", 10);       

            file(dest) << "\n//# sourceMappingURL=${baseName}.min.${md5}.js.map"
            Map srcMap = new JsonSlurper().parseText( sourceMap.text )
            srcMap.sources = ["${baseName}.js"]
            sourceMap.withWriter("UTF-8") { it << new JsonBuilder(srcMap).toPrettyString() }

            def finalFileName = "${baseName}.min.${md5}.js";

            file("${baseName}.min.js").renameTo(file(finalFileName))
            file("${baseName}.min.js.map").renameTo(file("${baseName}.min.${md5}.js.map"))
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the command `gradle cleanDist generateTask`, the tasks finishes with success, the combine files is generated, but minified files aren't generated.

In log show this:

```
Skipping task ':minify-store.js' as it is up-to-date (took 0.002 secs).
```

Any idea?

Comment: Run the script with `-i` (info) or `-d` (debug) switches and verify the info to check what the tasks are not run. Also, why do you generate the tasks dynamically?

Comment: My idea is have a configuration file, where are reported new minified files, without need create new tasks.